# Is it safe to create a QLayout on the stack?

Tags: c++, qt

I know fron the Qt documentation that the `QLayout` object assumes ownership of its widgets. But as far as the `QLayout` object is concerned, is it safe to create it on the stack and then pass it to a widget using the `setLayout` function? Or does it have to be created on the heap?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class LoudPushButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    virtual ~LoudPushButton(){std::cout << "~LoudPushButton()" << std::endl;}
};

class LoudQVBoxLayout : public QVBoxLayout
{
public:
    virtual ~LoudQVBoxLayout(){std::cout << "~LoudQVBoxLayout()" << std::endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    // On the heap
    LoudQVBoxLayout* mainlayout = new LoudQVBoxLayout;
    mainlayout->addWidget(new LoudPushButton);
    mainlayout->addWidget(new LoudPushButton);
    window.setLayout(mainlayout);
  /*
    // On the stack
    LoudQVBoxLayout mainlayout;
    mainlayout.addWidget(new LoudPushButton);   
    mainlayout.addWidget(new LoudPushButton);
    window.setLayout(&mainlayout);
  */
    window.show(); 

    return a.exec();
}
```

Both alternatives // On the stack and // On the heap produce the same result at the exit:

```
~LoudQVBoxLayout()
~LoudPushButton()
~LoudPushButton()
```

But can I be sure that this is not undefined behaviour? Does the `window` call `delete` on its layout?

EDIT:

In view of the answer by Cat Plus Plus I guess that:

```
LoudPushButton button;
mainlayout->addWidget(&button);
mainlayout->addWidget(new LoudPushButton);
```

Produces undefined behaviour even if the `button` and `*mainlayout` are guaranteed to be deleted at the same time. Is this true?

Comment: I think you should reconsider the accepted answer. I've edited my post with further details explaining how Cat Plus Plus's answer is contradicted by Qt's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt, object trees are designed such that QWidgets can be constructed on stack. So long as parents are created before children they will destruct properly. Neither of your examples are undefined behaviour.

The Qt documentation even [gives an example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html#construction-destruction-order-of-qobjects) and explains why it's legitimate to construct widgets with parents on the stack:

```
int main()
{
    QWidget window;
    QPushButton quit("Quit", &window);
    ...
}
```

> This code is correct: the destructor of quit is not called twice because the C++ language standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) specifies that destructors of local objects are called in the reverse order of their constructors. Therefore, the destructor of the child, quit, is called first, and it removes itself from its parent, window, before the destructor of window is called.

Layouts should also behave properly, as they are designed to be destroyed at any time. The `QWidget::setLayout` [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setLayout) mentions:

> If there already is a layout manager installed on this widget, QWidget won't let you install another. You must first delete the existing layout manager (returned by layout()) before you can call setLayout() with the new layout.

The Qt layout system tracks the lifetime of QLayout objects that have been set on QWidgets, and will handle destruction appropriately, as implied by this documentation. The destructor of QLayout includes code that unregisters it from the QWidget it is set on.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed post but I think one has to add a point to your explanation: While in this specific example it is safe to use the stack it is very dangerous to do so generally when using Qt due to the nasty problems that arise if child and parent construction are inverted.Since this can easily happen in larger functions I would recommend to use the heap to stay away clean from such subtleties

Answer (score 4):

Every `QObject` deletes its children. Only objects with no parent can have automatic storage. And `QWidget::setLayout` reparents the layout. So, no, you can't do that with `QLayout`.

Comment: Thank you! Please could you check my Edit to see if it is true?

Comment: The documentation says "The QWidget will take ownership of layout."  You can't have both the stack being responsible for deletion and the widget being responsible for deletion.  Even if you unwound the particulars and found a workaround in this implementation (for some strange esoteric reason of how the code is written right now), you should follow the contract...

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: Layout reparents widgets you add to it, so the same rule apply. Calling `delete` on a pointer to an automatic storage object is UB, regardless of when it happens.

Comment: I only mentioned the above because it's my opposite reaction to a lot of questions where I say *"go look at the source"*.  The fact is that Qt *could* (if it wanted to) detect deletions with the `QObject::destroyed` signal and not lead to undefined behavior...but it *doesn't*...and by documentation it *shouldn't*... http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#destroyed

Comment: Downvoting because this answer is incorrect. Objects with parents can have automatic storage, and you can do this with a layout. It's very clear from Qt's documentation. See my answer for further details.